# What is the difference between Natural type defined in GHC.Natural and Numeric.Natural in haskell?

Tags: haskell

As per the title of the question - what is the difference between `Natural` type defined in `GHC.Natural` and `Numeric.Natural` modules in haskell?

Which one should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same type. If you read [the source of Numeric.Natural](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/Numeric.Natural.html), you can see that it's a completely empty module except for re-exporting GHC's Natural type.

Comment: As for why it exists two places: `Numeric.Natural` is the API that could reasonably be implemented in various different ways, while `GHC.Natural` includes implementation details. The former gives you better stability/portability, while the latter presumably lets you do more things (or the same things with better efficiency).